# How to order WP_Query by parent for hierarchical Custom Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, menu-order

How can I get all items under specific parent and order them by menu order in hierarchical Custom Post Type?
Lets say I have this posts structure:

- Fruits

  - Apples
  - Bananas
  - Plum
  - Cherry
- Vegetables

  - Potatoes
  - Beans
  - Beet
- Nuts

  - Walnut
  - Chia seeds

This doesn't work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'vile',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_parent__in' => array(543), // Only children of Fruits or Vegetables or Nuts
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Registering CPT

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_vile', 0 );
function register_vile() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Vile', 'Vile', 'mytextdomain' ),
    );
    $args   = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Vile', 'mytextdomain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'post_tag' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
        'rewrite'             => array(
            'slug' => 'vile',
        ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'vile', $args );

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with these posts? It's hard to order posts in such way, because the structure is a tree, so you'll need a Walker to flatten that tree...

Comment: I need to display them in a loop and maybe pagination will be needed, something like archive page for each of those main posts. The structure is as it is, I can't change them to categories